# What is determining the height of this <section> element?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm using a basic template that I ran across.  I'm using it internally to display information and I was looking for something with a layout like this.

What I am trying to accomplish is to make the #banner element shorter.  Around 300px or any equivalent size.  Just not the 700px or so it is now.

[Template I am using](https://templated.co/transit)

Here is the #banner section from style.css

```
/* Banner */
#banner {
    background-color: #6a86b0;
    background-image: url("../images/mainHelperBanner.jpg");
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #d8d8d8;
    padding: 14em 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
    #banner:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background: rgba(64, 72, 80, 0.25);
    }
    #banner .inner {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
        #banner .inner :last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    #banner h2, #banner h3, #banner h4, #banner h5, #banner h6 {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    #banner .button.alt {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.75);
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }
        #banner .button.alt:hover {
            background-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.275);
        }
        #banner .button.alt:active {
            background-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.4);
        }
        #banner .button.alt.icon:before {
            color: #c1c1c1;
        }
    #banner .button {
        min-width: 12em;
    }
    #banner h2 {
        font-size: 3.5em;
        line-height: 1em;
        margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #banner p {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
        #banner p a {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Here is the html from my index.

```
<!-- Banner -->
<section id="banner">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2>Integrator</h2>
        <p>Teams/sharepoint/tigerpaw/appenate</a></p>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><a href="#content" class="button big special">xx</a></li>
            <li><a href="#elements" class="button big alt">xx</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

What I have tried:

After replacing the stock image with a correctly sized one of my own I changed

```
 background-size: cover;
```

to

```
 background-size: auto;
```

With no noticable result. Someone suggested it had to do with padding.  So  I've changed

```
 padding: 14em 0;
```

to numerous different values and nothing changes.  I've also changed the ( banner:before)

```
    height: 50%;
```

to a few different values and no change.

My css level is intermediate I'd say, I know enough to usually do what I want but in this case I'm stumped.  I don't see any other setting that should affect height.

EDIT:  It was padding but it was being overwritten by this :

```
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-xlarge.css" />
</noscript>
```

As soon as I removed the link to style-xlarge.css it started to listen to the padding settings.

What I don't understand is this.  When I first installed this template flask wasn't happy finding those links.  It found all the  links but not these until the noscript tag was removed.

If this is the full head

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Transit by TEMPLATED</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-xlarge.css" />
</noscript>
```

What is the point of the noscript tags in this case? My understanding is that it provides for when the browser has scripting disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `padding` to something like this to shorten your #banner section height:

```
padding: 6em 0em;
```

Comment: I've tried multiple settings for that and nothing changes visually.

Comment: Hm... I've opened your template link with Chrome DevTools and changed padding on element with id #banner to padding setting mentioned above. For me it works and shortens height of the section. Do you have a link to your site? Maybe you've set something else or is code different?

Comment: It's not public facing just internal.   I'm using the included index to test, I haven't added anything of mine yet.  Not that it should matter but this is part of a flask app.   I'm looking at it right now in chrome, with dev tools and no matter what changes, I'm still left with that gigantic blue box.  Padding seems to keep the image the right size but the overall box its in is still the same size.

Comment: OK, I've taken screenshot: https://ibb.co/0FwCzmt Is this what you expect?

Comment: I can't tell, here is how I described it to someone else.  These are with my image.  [Original](https://imgur.com/plL15YW)

[What I want](https://imgur.com/S8Vr3ya)  Does that make it clearer?  Are you saying that all you changed was the padding?

Comment: Ok. I think I know what is going here, or at least partially. It's linking to another style sheet.  I didn't notice it before.    So you were right, it was padding, but its being overwritten.

Comment: Yes, this could cause you problems. Try to add !important after the padding setting like this: `padding: 6em 0em !important;`

Comment: I just edited my original question with new info.  Padding works now that its not being overwritten.   It led me to another question about how these files are included.

Comment: Yes, noscript tags are for loading files when scripting is disabled. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: Something is not right since the only way this works is commenting those out, but for the moment it works for my purposes.  I'm wondering if something in jinja2 is unhappy.  I'm going to mark your answer as it was padding, thanks for your help.